# Tkinter (python3) How to insert text vertically in Text widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i have create a botton with Tkinter, like this:

```
self.calc_amm = Button(self.window)
self.calc_amm["text"] = "Calcola"
self.calc_amm["command"] = lambda: self.testo.insert(1.0, (operazioni.ammortamento(var_sel.get(), self.inserisci_imponibile.get(), self.inserisci_tasso.get(), var_periodo.get(), self.durata.get())))
self.calc_amm.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 2, pady = 2)
```

where

```
self.calc_amm["command"] = lambda: self.**testo**.insert(1.0, (operazioni.ammortamento(var_sel.get(), self.inserisci_imponibile.get(), self.inserisci_tasso.get(), var_periodo.get(), self.durata.get())))
```

"testo" is

```
self.testo = Text(f)
self.testo["background"] = "white"
self.testo.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
```

The idea is get the value `var_sel.get(), self.inserisci_imponibile.get(), self.inserisci_tasso.get(), var_periodo.get(), self.durata.get()` and pass the values to the function `operazioni.ammortamento(a,b,c,d,e)`.
In the function `operazioni.ammortamento(a,b,c,d,e)` i do some calculations, and return 3 lists (`return(arr_rata, arr_quota_cap, arr_cap_res)`).

My output, in the Text widget, is as follows:

```
{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10} {5000 5000 5000 5000 5000 5000 5000 5000 5000 5000} {4500 4000 3500 3000 2500 2000 1500 1000 500 0}
```

How can I do to have the output like as follows???

```
Something: Someth.:   Someth.:
{1          5000      4500
2           5000      4000
3           5000      3500
4           5000      3000
5           5000      2500
6           5000      2000
7           5000      1500
8           5000      1000
9           5000       500
10}         5000         0
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like you just need to get the first element of the first list, first element of the second list, first element of the third list, and add spaces. Then do the same for each other element. Have you tried that?

Comment: Exact! I tried in different ways to do what you suggested, but with poor results. I tried to change several times the function "operazioni.ammortamento(a,b,c,d,e)", but once the lists are returned I can not manage to print them vertically.

I probably should change the lambda function, but I just can not find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make it work, then make it beautiful; You have three lists:

```
arr_rata = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
arr_quota_cap = [5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000]
arr_cap_res = [4500, 4000, 3500, 3000, 2500, 2000, 1500, 1000, 500, 0]
```

Making a Text widget as an example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
testo = Text(root, width=40, height=15)
testo.grid(padx=10, pady=10, sticky='nsew')
```

Print them to Text widget one index at a time:

```
testo.delete(1.0,END)   # Delete text from widget if there is any
testo.insert(END,'rata:   quota_cap:   cap_res:\n')
for index in range(len(arr_rata)):
    col1 = '{:<8}'.format(arr_rata[index])
    col2 = '{:<13}'.format(arr_quota_cap[index])
    col3 = '{}'.format(arr_cap_res[index])
    line = col1 + col2 + col3 + '\n'
    testo.insert(END,line)
```

You can rewrite it with list comprehension or lambda later if you think it's necessary.

Also see [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: Thank you @figbeam! It works perfectly. One last question please: with `print('{:<7}'.format(arr_rata[index]),'{:<12}'.format(arr_quota_cap[index]),
          arr_cap_res[index])`, the result is printed in the terminal which opens when I start the python file. How can i put the result inside the text widget that i called "testo"?  Should I put everything inside the lambda function that I use to call "operazioni.ammortamento"?

Comment: Rewrote the example for writing to Text widget.